# How to programmatically make a LinearLayout placed in the right side of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have an Image and text view that generated programmatically but I faced the problem how to make the `LinearLayout` margin parent right 
this bellow my code

```
 LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearChat);
 final ImageView img1 = new ImageView(context);
 final TextView tv1 = new TextView(context);
 tv1.setText(chat.getPesan());
        img1.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cservice));
        lin.addView(tv1);
        tv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner1);
        tv1.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        lin.addView(img1);
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear on what you are trying to make?

Comment: An image of what you have now and what you want would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the `setMargin()` line,

```
// Left Top Right Bottom Margin
tv1.setMargins(25,25,25,25);  // adjust according to your need
```

Comment: Yeah..! It's Working.